# Start Wordpress From Scratch with New Theme

Tags: wordpress

I built a website for a client ages ago when I still used Wordpress.  The client recently came to me with a new theme they wanted.  Unfortunately the old theme doesn't move everything nicely into the new one.

Is there a way I can start a new site from scratch, then move it to production?

Comment: Can you specify the WordPress version your old theme supported and what version your new theme supports?

Answer (score 0):

1. Export the old database to your computer (client's server)

   2. Create a new database (client's server)
   3. Import old database file to the new database (client's server)
   4. Create a folder inside server, called newSite,
   5. Install all the wordpress core flies and theme there.
   6. Conect the new instalation with the new database.

Now you have a start point

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply.

I talked to the client and it looks like we are just going to start from scratch.  I will pitch to him that it doesn't have to be like that.

Thanks a ton for your help!